# How to capitalize each word of an <input> using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

i am try some code got it from here but it is capitalizing just the first word of the sentence

```js
function capitalize(textboxid, str) {
  // string with alteast one character
  if (str && str.length >= 1) {
    var firstChar = str.charAt(0);
    var remainingStr = str.slice(1);
    str = firstChar.toUpperCase() + remainingStr + " ";
  }
  document.getElementById(textboxid).value = str;
}
```

```html
<input name="sentence" id="sentencebox" onkeyup="javascript:capitalize(this.id, this.value);" placeholder="Write a Sentence" class="form-control" type="text">
```

Comment: CSS can do that in one line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly, this will replace any word with 2+ characters in it, if you dont want that just replace the regex with `/\b([a-z])[a-z]*?/gi`

```js
function capitalize(inputField) {
  inputField.value = inputField.value.replace(/\b[a-z](?=[a-z]{2})/gi, function(letter) {
    return letter.toUpperCase();
  });
}
```

```html
<input name="sentence" id="sentencebox" onkeyup="javascript:capitalize(this);" placeholder="Write a Sentence" class="form-control" type="text">
```

P.S. you can just use css to achieve the same effect:

```
#senterncebox:first-letter {
   text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

css is neater in my opinion, since pressing shortcuts like  (ctrl+a) simply works out of the box.

Comment: #senterncebox:first-letter {
   text-transform: uppercase;
} <-- but not in the database.

Comment: function capitalize(inputField) {
  inputField.value = inputField.value.replace(/\b[a-z](?=[a-z]{2})/gi, function(letter) {
    return letter.toUpperCase();
  });
} <--- it words capitlizing each first word in the sentence both from input box and database. thank you

Answer (score 2):

This is another way to capitalize first letter of each word

```js
function capitalize(obj) {
  str = obj.value;
  obj.value = str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt) {
    return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
  });
}
```

```html
<input name="sentence" id="sentencebox" onkeyup="javascript:capitalize(this);" placeholder="Write a Sentence" class="form-control" type="text">
```

Comment: you can use capture groups to capture what youre interested in, instead of all the charAt and the substrings.

Comment: You are welcome, this appreciation really motivate us to help others, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should split the string on spaces and run the same basic logic against each element and join again using ' ':

```js
var capitalized = "the quick brown fox".split(' ').map(function(word) {
    return word[0].toUpperCase() + word.slice(1)
}).join(' ');
console.log(capitalized)
```